# How to pass IUnknown argument to a COM interface using C#?

Tags: c#, com, iunknown, com-interface

I have a COM interface defined like this

```
interface Client : IUnknown
{
    [id(1)] HRESULT GetSomething
    (
        enum SomeID someID,
        [out] IUnknown  **pUnknown
    );
};
```

How can I pass `IUnknown` object using C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't pass anything, it **returns** an interface pointer.  An opaque one, IUnknown is implemented by all COM interfaces.  In C# it will be an object of type *object*, the managed version of "could be anything".  So basic code looks like this:

```
object retval;
client.GetSomething(SomeID.Magic, out retval);
```

And then it is up to you to cast the returned object into the actual interface type, probably based on *Magic*.  Your question gives no hint at all what it might be, you'll have to read the documentation of the COM component to have an idea.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't know *anything* about the object, you would probably use an IntPtr to represent the IUnknown and then get a RCW for it using [Marshal.GetUniqueObjectForIUnknown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getuniqueobjectforiunknown%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
// Get some object

IntPtr ptrObj = IntPtr.Zero;


Client.GetSomething(someID, out ptrObj);
object obj = Marshal.GetUniqueObjectForIUnknown(ptrIProfferService);
```